# Use Confluent Hub without Confluent Platform installation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using these installation instructions for getting confluent hub client https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html

But, when I get to the line to install the kafka-connect-elasticsearch connector

`confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch:latest`

I continue to get this error message:

```
Unable to detect Confluent Platform installation. Specify --component-dir and --worker-configs explicitly.

Error: Invalid options or arguments
```

I have ElasticSearch and Kafka all installed via Homebrew on my Mac

Answer (score 14):

> Specify --component-dir and --worker-configs explicitly

You'll have to pass both options to include the Homebrew location of Kafka Connect's `plugin.path` setting (where Confluent Hub would install to) and your `connect-distributed.properties` (so that the plugin path can be setup if it isn't already)

e.g. (on a Mac, after `brew install kafka`)

```
confluent-hub install <name> \
   --component-dir /usr/local/Cellar/kafka/plugins \
   --worker-configs /usr/local/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties
```

This command should download and extract the connector zip into `/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/plugins` and modify the `connect-distributed.properties` file to include that path in its `plugin.path` property

[Here is an example using a Kafka Connect docker image that I've built](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker#extending-with-new-connectors)

Comment: are there suggested locations for both these parameters?

Comment: @bagi I would say a location where the service account running Kafka Connect has access to read them. By default in Confluent Platform, components are installed under `/usr/share/java` and configs are placed within `/etc`

Comment: How to find these paths? If installed from docker?

Comment: @Megan The confluentinc connect container is already pre-configured for using Confluent Hub, so you don't need to specify them. You can find examples of usage by blog posts from rmoff

Answer (score 2):

**MacOS**

In my case I have installed Kafka and Confluent Hub with `brew` and the installation path for Kafka is `/usr/local/Cellar/kafka`. And created a directory to install the connector.

Move to `/usr/local/Caskroom/confluent-hub-client/6.2.1/bin`, it is the directory confluent-hub is located.

Then I've executed

```
confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-blob-storage:1.6.2 \
  --component-dir /Users/Rustam_Zokirov/BigData/connectors \
  --worker-configs /usr/local/Cellar/kafka/3.0.0/libexec/config/connect-distributed.properties
```

Comment: Thanks! For M1 Mac, homebrew installed kafka here instead: 
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/kafka/3.3.1_1/libexec/config/connect-distributed.properties` . Then I created the other directory for `--component-dir`