# how to install Debezium mysql or other kafka connectors without Confluent-Hub

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I installed Confluent using Docker and all the services are up And I created a topic successfully.

[image]

I can not install Confluent-Hub and I want to connect mysql using debezuim.

how to install mysql or other kafka connectors without Confluent-Hub and create container for docker

Answer (score 0):

[The Confluent connect container comes with Confluent-hub installed](https://rmoff.net/2020/06/19/how-to-install-connector-plugins-in-kafka-connect/)

If you want to use Debezium images rather than Confluent's, then [mysql connector is already there](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html)

Otherwise, the Connector pages on the Hub website describe exactly how to download the Zip files yourself, which you'd extract into the `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` Docker env var for the Confluent Connect container

**Related question**

[Use Confluent Hub without Confluent Platform installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation/57051446)

Comment: Download and unzip confluent-hub-client-latest.tar.gz. Add the contents of the bin directory to your PATH environment variable so that which confluent-hub finds the confluent-hub command

Comment: Like I said, you don't need to extract anything - in Docker, the binary is already there. Adding the hub client to your host wouldn't allow you to easily modify and Docker images. Also, it's not necessary to modify your host PATH, but if this post has answered your question, feel free to use the checkmark next to it to accept it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063604/confluent-mysql-connect-with-debizuim-error