# confluent mysql connect with debizuim error

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have installed Confluent on Docker and all services are up.

[image]

this is my connector plugins

[image]

and this is my connector config

```
{
 "name": "inventory-connector",
 "config": {
     "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
     "tasks.max": "1",
     "database.hostname": "mysql",
     "database.port": "3306",
     "database.user": "root",
     "database.password": "mypassword",
     "database.server.id": "184054",
     "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
     "database.whitelist": "inventory",
     "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
     "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory"
     }
 }
```

but, after send it for create connector this error accoured

[image]

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 21 Jun 2021 06:52:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 397
Server: Jetty(9.4.40.v20210413)

{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nUnable to connect: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}

Comment: Where is your mysql server? Can the docker container successful route a connection to it?

Comment: Your image shows no container named `mysql` or anything using port 3306. Also, `kafka.bootstrap.servers` cannot be `localhost`... It needs to be the Kafka container name

Comment: mysql is running :( I did not show in the photo

Answer (score 0):

change your `database.hostname`. The `database.hostname` should be your database host where where your `mysql` is running. If it is in your local machine then check your local machine IP and add it to `database.hostname`.

Example: `database.hostname = 192.163.13.124`