# Upgrading apache kafka to confluent platform

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are planning to upgrade our existing apache kafka cluster to confluent kafka while upgrading do we have any data loss in the topics?? And also main reason we are upgrading is to use s3 sink connector is there any connector which is available in apache kafka itself?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to migrate to [*Confluent Server*](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/migrate-confluent-server.html), there is nothing you need to migrate; Confluent Platform includes Apache Kafka

Kafka Connect, on the other hand, is a pluggable environment, and doesn't require Confluent tools/systems other than [the specific JAR file(s) for the S3 Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/overview.html#install-the-amazon-s3-sink-connector)

Comment: just to clear I have downloaded kafka from https://kafka.apache.org/downloads is this enough to use the S3 connecter or do I need to install kafka here http://packages.confluent.io/archive/6.2/confluent-community-6.2.0.tar.gz <-- is this is yes... Do I need to start the zookeeper and kafka from confluent and stop apache kafka or only using the S3 connector is fine.. Am a beginner to kafka any help on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: 1) Download (or use current) Kafka installation, which includes Connect 2) Download the S3 Connector archive or (recommended) [use `confluent-hub --install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation) 3) Verify `plugin.path` in the Connector properties is correct 4) Start Connect server and inspect the logs, or use `GET /connector-plugins` to see if the class was loaded... The same applies to all plugins for Connect, and has no specific need for Confluent Platform until you start adding Schema Registry or Control Center

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 sink connector from apache camel

https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/connectors/camel-aws-s3-sink-kafka-sink-connector.html

1. Just need to download the S3 sink connector jar file from this link:
   https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/index.html
2. Copy the jar file in connector plugins path. It depends on value of your properties. By default on the relative path: plugins/connectors, or set in plugin.path property.

So you don't need to restart and lost any data.