# Kafka ConnectStandalone - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I am running Kafka Connect standalone

```
$ kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin$ connect-standalone.sh ../config/connect-standalone.properties ../config/connect-snowflake-kafka-connector.properties ../libs/snowflake-kafka-connector-1.5.5.jar
```

Getting error of the Snowflake Apache Kafka error. Error enclosed in the image attached

[image]

```
[2021-09-07 14:56:45,843] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=snowflakeslink-0} Initializing and starting task for topics test-topic (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:299)
[2021-09-07 14:56:45,844] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:start (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:101)
[2021-09-07 14:56:45,856] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:574)
```

Comment: How does your properties file looks like? The error suggest the issue is with one of the properties.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As @Sergiu said, please edit your question to include your configuration file, and also the command you're using to launch Kafka Connect. Also, it's much better to include the log file text itself in your question instead of an image as it makes it easier for others to read and to search for similar errors in the future.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

connect-standalone.sh accepts only properties files arguments. If you are providing it a JAR file as a shell argument, it'll try to parse it as a property file, and will fail

---

Your snowflake driver JAR should be added to the Java `CLASSPATH` via an `export`, not as a parameter to the script.

e.g.

```
$ export CLASSPATH='/path/to/snowflake-client-driver.jar'
$ connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties snowflake-demo-standalone.properties
```

However (recommended), use `confluent hub install` - https://www.confluent.io/hub/snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector

**Related Post** - [Use Confluent Hub without Confluent Platform installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation/57051446)

This will update the configuration property **`plugin.path`** for adding the connector classes

Comment: Thank you it helped me, I removed the .jar file while executing the connector properties. But now getting error[2021-09-07 19:27:23,254] WARN [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-snowflakeslink-0, groupId=connect-snowflakeslink] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:769)

Comment: Well, is Kafka running on localhost?

Comment: Yes its up and running .kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin$ jps
6728 Kafka
9592 ConsoleConsumer
25257 Jps
6332 QuorumPeerMain

Comment: If the console consumer can work with `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` , then Connect should too

Comment: WARN [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Unexpected error from /127.0.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369296129 larger than 104857600)
 in KAFKA logs

Comment: I don't think that is related to a consumer process

Comment: Then how can overcome this error? Any idea please

Comment: I've not seen that message before, so I don't know. Two possible ideas... Stop Zookeeper, and the broker. Delete all the data directories, and start over? Run a lower version of Kafka that might be more stable than the latest release? Regardless, I've answered the exception in your post, and you should create a new post for new errors that occur