# Loading CSV data into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I was working on event monitoring / microservice monitoring with kafka.

Following a guide from https://rmoff.net/2020/06/17/loading-csv-data-into-kafka/

When i was at the area

```
    kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -t orders_spooldir_00 \
             -C -o-1 -J \
             -s key=s -s value=avro -r http://schema-registry:8081 | \
             jq '.payload'
```

I got an error, not sure what went wrong, docker end or the server end?
Would appreciate any helps on how I can proceed! thanks

```
% ERROR: Failed to query metadata for topic orders_spooldir_00: Local: Broker transport failure
```

```
kafka-connect      | [2021-11-09 16:02:35,778] ERROR [source-csv-spooldir-00|worker] WorkerConnector{id=source-csv-spooldir-00} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:193)
```

Comment: For a school project, the FOSS Kafka connector is good enough.

Comment: Your question title says `connector` - can you edit your question to include detail of what connector you're wanting to use?

Comment: Bear in mind that Confluent includes many components that are freely available under the Confluent Community Licence.

Comment: hi Robin, I want to use a connector that can possibly connect Kafka with HTML web applications.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question to include what specifically you tried. You can use [Confluent Hub without Confluent Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation).

Comment: Note that Confluent Platform **includes** the open-source, Apache Kafka. There is  no difference in what you're asking.

Comment: ok, i will set up a new question with more details on what i tried

Comment: You can [edit] this current question rather than make a new one