# Use kafka connect without docker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I just finished the udemy course on kafka connect,
the course is based on docker, but what should I do not want to use docker?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka connect requires JVM. Although you can run it only with JRE, I recommend installing jdk (like openjdk). Download JAR from https://packages.confluent.io/archive/6.2/ (or version that you prefer). And run it as java process passing parameters file as a configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Confluent Platform. Download Kafka from Apache website. It comes with all [commands to run Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect). The only requirement is Java (version 11 is recommended, although 17 is the latest supported).

To install connectors, you [can use `confluent-hub` without Confluent Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation/57051446)