# Sending data from elasticsearch to kafka and finally to influxdb?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to know how can I send data from elasticsearch to kafka and then to influxdb?
I've already tried using confluent platform with sources connector from elasticsearch and sink connector from influxdb, but the problem is that I'm stuck on sending data from elasticsearch to kafka

moreover once my computer is off I no longer have the backup of the connectors and I have to start from scratch

that's why my questions:

- How to send data from elasticsearch to kafka? using confluent platform?
- Do I really have to use confluent platform if I want to use kafka connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect is Apache 2.0 Licensed and is included with Apache Kafka download.

Confluent (among other companies) write plugins for it, such as Sinks to Elasticsearch or Influx.

It appears the Elasticsearch source on Confluent Hub is not built by Confluent, for example.

Related - [Use Confluent Hub without Confluent Platform installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation/57051446)

> once my computer is off I no longer have the backup of the connectors and I have to start from scratch

Kafka Connect distributed mode stores its config data in Kafka topics... Kafka defaults to store topic data in /tmp... Which is deleted when you shutdown your computer

Similarly, if you are using Docker for any of these systems without mounted volumes, Docker also is not persistent by default

Comment: so what will be the best option for me to create this little elasticsearch -> kafka -> influxdb pipeline?

Comment: I didn't say it was best. I was only answering that Confluent Platform is not a requirement. However, the Elasticsearch source or Influx sink may require you to purchase a license agreement with Confluent to use those connectors for longer than 30 days

Comment: See https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/influxdb/current/index.html#license

Comment: I understand then I am already on the right path when I was able to create the elasticsearch source connector and influxdb sink connector with confluent platform.
what about how do i send data from elasticsearch to kafka? normally we use elasticsearch source connector and how I do after that is still a mystery to me

Comment: I dont understand your question. Source connectors, by definition, send data to Kafka. Confluent Platform includes Apache Kafka; they are not separate things, and as mentioned, you're not required to use Confluent Platform.

Comment: ok, I understand, I can use confluent sources and sink connector without going through confluent platform. So how do I mount my little pipeline?
in the udemy course they use docker with landoop. Do you have any links or books that I will need so that I can fully understand once and for all?

Comment: I have already invested in training and books but I think I'm stuck in practice: creating your very first pipeline. thanks

Comment: Kafka connect starts a http endpoint. Landoop connect UI simply talks to that. Docker is not required, either... You can consult the Apache Kafka documentation for how to run connect process itself. Regarding pipelines, start here https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/

Comment: Why Docker is not required? I check this course and they use docker to run landoop, elasticsearch... https://courses.datacumulus.com/downloads/kafka-connect-09a/

Comment: Everything can run on your host machine without needing Docker. Docker is never required for any software since it just runs plain Linux processes.

Comment: So have you a useful link about landoop connect UI?

Comment: That project is open source and available on Github, I trust your own ability to find it. However, is no longer maintained, and you don't need any UI to use Kafka Connect

Comment: I have another question, how do we do for example for the case of the confluent kafka influxdb connector when this one requires influxdb 1.X when what I want is to connect with influxdb 2.X should I create myself even the connector in this case?

Comment: I don't have experience with InfluxDB to answer that, but you could look at using Telegraf instead of Kafka Connect.