# Kafka S3 Sink basic doubts

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

Do I really need to use confluent (CLI maybe)? Can I write my custom connector?
How can I write my first Kafka Sink? How to deploy them?

For now, let's assume we have the following details:

```
Topic: curious.topic
S3 bucket name: curious.s3
Data in the topic: Text/String
My OS: Mac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [start at the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/overview.html) for S3 Sink, looking over the configuration properties, and understand how to [run Connect itself](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) and deploy *any connector* (use the REST API); no, `confluent` CLI is never needed.

You don't need to "write your own sink" because Confluent already has an S3 Sink Connector. Sure, you could fork their open-source repo, and compile it yourself, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

You can download the connector using different command [`confluent-hub`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation/57051446).

Note: [pinterest/secor](https://github.com/pinterest/secor) does the same thing, without Kafka Connect.