# Insert consumed data from kafka topic into SQL Database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

we are working on a project to consume data from kafka topics and insert it into a SQL database.
What confuses me is that Apache Kafka does not have a connector for SQL databases, and the other option is to use Confluent Kafka instead.

So please let me know the correct way in order to proceed forwarder from my side

Comment: You need to write this code yourself. Here's an [example](https://github.com/quixio/quix-samples/tree/main/python/destinations) for Postgres that uses their FOSS stream processing library: [Quix Streams](https://github.com/quixio/quix-streams)

Comment: Do you mean the java or python code that will be used to insert the consumed data into the database table?

Answer (score 0):

"Confluent Kafka" is not a thing; Confluent, *the company*, writes plugins for Kafka Connect, which is available in **any** distribution of Apache Kafka, such as Confluent ***Platform***.

For example, both IBM and Aiven maintain JDBC Kafka Connect sink plugins, *in addition to* Confluent.

The only plugins that Kafka Connect comes with are for local filesystem files and MirrorMaker2.

[`confluent-hub` CLI works without Confluent Platform for installing such plugins.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958382/use-confluent-hub-without-confluent-platform-installation/57051446)

Alternatively, you can use Spark, Flink, NiFi, etc for writing to databases without Kafka Connect, or use built-in Kafka ingestion features of certain databases like Pinot, Couchbase, Clickhouse, Telegraf+InfluxDB, Logstash+Elasticsearch, as some examples. SQL shouldn't be your only option, IMO

Comment: Hello, Crick. I'd like to thank you for your consistent responses to my stackoverflow questions. Regarding the comment you made,
I'm already using Apache Kafka, and I had this problem before when trying to consume data in Avro format, which required me to use Confluent Kafka instead of Apache to use the schema registry module.
For now, the SQL database connector can be used directly with Apache without the need for Confluent. Else for Spark, Do you use spark data frame to write directly to a database table? If so, could you please share the document that will assist you in doing so?

Comment: 1) As answered, there's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". Avro Schema Registry servers are implemented by more companies than just Confluent,such as Apicurio by Red Hat, and they all work with **Apache** Kafka 2) Yes, SparkSQL can write to databases, refer Spark docs on JDBC driver, or external sources like Mongo documentation. Or, like I said, use a database engine that has native Kafka ingestion support